# C# - Check if user is logged in Facebook

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I'm working on a Windows Phone Silverlight app and I want to make a simple login via Facebook(browser). Is there a way to check if the user is logged in Facebook? I redirect the user to Facebook page with this statement:

```
Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("http://www.facebook.com"));
```

Comment: Check [this](http://codes2know.com/facebook-integration-with-c-net/) out. It has information about FB Graph API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you are using the windows SDK for facebook 
(https://github.com/Microsoft/winsdkfb) but it is a third party sdk approved by Facebook.

Before using that SDK you should set up the Facebook developer page for your app. (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apis-and-sdks)

I hope that helps.

Comment: Are you using the Microsoft SDK for Facebook?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a WPF example that uses the WebBrowser class to get a token: [Facebook OAuth in WPF & C# Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20353702/facebook-oauth-in-wpf-c-sharp-example)

Obviously the WPF related things might differ a bit, but it should at least point you to getting the info you need out of the process. As far as checking whether the user is logged in, I pretty much just checked whether the token is valid by making some http request that uses it and seeing whether it was successful (used a REST client for that).

There was a way to directly check token validity via the Facebook APIs but that was deprecated last I checked.