# Is there a way to direct googles OAuth 2 authentication to a C# WPF Browser within a desktop app?

Tags: c#, wpf, google-analytics-firebase

The default behaviour google uses for authenticating users right now is to open up the default system browser and have the user log into the account associated with the application, and then leave it up to the user to return to the application.

Since I can't avoid this process I was hoping I could make the authentication process take place within a wpf browser control so that its a bit friendlier to the user.

Is it possible to make this authentication happen in the browser control?

Comment: you can always embed a browser inside WPF and then take the Auth cookie once it is done. Not sure if google allows this but that's how I do it for my own project

Comment: It is possible to use a browser control for OAuth, however, it is not recommended. https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-oauth-native-apps-03#section-8.1

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty lengthy stackoverflow question which appears more as an answer =) or an example. It does the Auth flow with Facebook but I am sure the concepts apply to google as well.

[Facebook OAuth in WPF & C# Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20353702/facebook-oauth-in-wpf-c-sharp-example)

HTH